# Storing Users Location Questionnaire Site

Tags: sql-server, database-design, server, normalization

Im building a website that has questionnaire that users fill out. Currently my db looks something like below.

**Website Questionnaire Consists of**

- 25 Questions
- 4 to 6 Answers per questions the user can choose from.

**Issue**

- I want to add in the users country, state / province / city.
- I need to incorporate this into my search function. See sql statement below.
- The client provided me a list of 23 countries to store and 750 states/provinces and about 6000 cities.

Were should this go in my db? Im completely lost on this one?

**Current DB Design**
See fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf068/1

```
User_Table 
ID | UserName
0  | Jack
...

User Questionnaire_Questions_Answer
ID | user_id | question_id | answer_id
0  | 0       | 0           | 0
1  | 0       | 1           | 3
...

Questionnaire_Questions
ID | Question
0  | What type of music do you like?
1  | What is your favorite sport ?
...

Questionnaire_Answers
ID | Answer
0  | Rock
1  | Rap
2  | Basketball
3  | Soccer
...
```

**SQL STATEMENT FOR SEARCH**

Searches best questionnaire results based on what the preferences the user is looking for, Sorts on Count on highest totalmatches

```
SELECT 
User_Table.id,
User_Table.UserName,
COUNT(User_Table.id) as totalMatches

FROM User_Table 
INNER JOIN Questionnaire_Questions_Answer ON User_Table.id = Questionnaire_Questions_Answer.user_ID
INNER JOIN Questionnaire_Questions ON Questionnaire_Questions.id = Questionnaire_Questions_Answer.question_ID
INNER JOIN Questionnaire_Answers on Questionnaire_Answers.id = Questionnaire_Questions_Answer.answer_ID
WHERE

--Q and A Requested to Match
Questionnaire_Questions.id = '0' and Questionnaire_Answers.answer = '0'
OR 
Questionnaire_Questions.id = '1' and Questionnaire_Answers.answer = '3'

GROUP BY User_Table.id
ORDER BY totalMatches DESC
```

Example Results

```
ID | Name | totalMatches
0  | Jack | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

create a location table as so:

```
create table dbo.location (id int identity,
country varchar(200),  
state_province varchar(100),  
city varchar 100))
```

when you add a user add the id of the location to the user table.